# How do you select and remove an element without removing the contents of the element javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, wordpress

I am working with WordPress theme, and there is a loop that pulls posts and creates the links to those posts. I am trying to remove the a tag but still leave the content in there.

```
<div class="members">
 <div class="wrapper">
   <a href="somelink">
     <img />
     <p>mycontent</p>
   </a>
 </div>
</div>
```

the advice i got was select the a and put it into a variable calling it target.
Then grab the inner html and add it to another variable called content.
Finally remove target and put the content back into the wrapper div.
I been having trouble selecting the a tag since it doesn't have a class and is inside of other divs.

Comment: Why don't you edit the php which generates the code?

Comment: The reason i can't use php is because i am stuck using visual composer. I can't really mess with or remove the code, but i can add javascript, html, and css.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `$.html()` to get the contents of the link, insert that content after the link using `$.after()`, then remove the link with `$.remove()`

```js
var $link = $('a'),
    stuff = $link.html();
$link.after(stuff).remove();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="members">
 <div class="wrapper">
   <a href="somelink">
     <img />
     <p>mycontent</p>
   </a>
 </div>
</div>
```

Or using vanilla JS, just use `innerHTML` to get the contents of the link and set that as the `innerHTML` of the wrapper.

```js
var wrapper = document.getElementsByClassName('wrapper')[0],
    link = wrapper.getElementsByTagName('a')[0];
wrapper.innerHTML = link.innerHTML;
```

```html
<div class="members">
 <div class="wrapper">
   <a href="somelink">
     <img />
     <p>mycontent</p>
   </a>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This seems to sort of work, but i have been just informed not to use jquery. >.< I'm sorry.

Comment: Assuming it's the first one (class wrapper)... dangerous

Comment: @DarrenSweeney feel free to submit a better answer. For OP's example, it's fine. If they have more than one wrapper, they can loop through them with the same method. But they don't in the example, so it isn't necessary to do that here.

Comment: I'm not criticizing, I'm just saying... unless there is another identifier I agree, this is the best solution, but, perhaps an idea to quantify that

Comment: @DarrenSweeney I'm aware it wouldn't work if there are more than 1, but if that's the case, isn't the responsibility on OP to give us code that represents that caveat? What is your suggestion? Should I create more than 1 wrapper in the code and assume that's what they're doing? If I were to modify their HTML, I would add an ID and target that way instead of using class/tag names. Heck, their real HTML could be multiple `.members` with a single `.wrapper` and `a` tag, so the real end goal should loop through `.members` and use the code I provided referencing the `0` index as it is.

Answer (score 0):

Am I missing something here...just use `$("#mylink").removeAttr("href");`

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $("#remove-tag").click(function() {

    $("#my-link").removeAttr("href");

  });


});
```

Comment: Oh, actually I was missing something....duh. He asked to remove the entire ```a``` tag. Oooops....though this should still work for you. Wouldn't be the best, but I'll leave the answer until someone thinks otherwise.

Comment: Thanks for the help anyway ^ .^